# Google App Engine Admin vs Application Admin

Tags: google-app-engine

I am building an application to deploy on GAE. It is a shopping application, and there will be users (administrators) who will need to login to the application and process incoming orders. My question is, from Google's perspective, an administrator role is more of a person who administers the application in terms of bringing it up or down, or has the ability to make changes to the datastore, view the console, etc, is that correct?

I'm asking because I'm not sure if I want to assign the people who will be filling orders as administrators from the GAE side of the house, I'm thinking that from within my application, I should have the users have their own roles, and assign those people as administrators within the application, since they don't have a need to be able to mess with the deployed application or app settings, etc.

Does that seem like a sensible approach?

Comment: Defining your own app-specific roles, via an entity kind in storage keyed by logged-in userid (whatever authentication scheme you choose), is a **very** appropriate pattern in many apps.  How specifically to code it is of course programming-language dependent, I could show an example of how to do it with Python in `ndb` but that might be useless if you use PHP or Java:-).  The GAE's own concept of `admin` users, as you surmise, is quite separate from what a user should be able to do in the context of the application itself.  Great question BTW!

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'm using JAVA to and any examples you have would be great. Right now I have an enum attribute in the User class that is of type Role. The coding is a little weird because I'm used to just calling isUserInRole on the request, but since GAE is only aware of whether or not i'm admin/not as far as the GAE defined roles are concerned, and has no knowledge of my application-level roles, I just have to keep that in the back of my mind. My approach was going to be to call myUser.getRole().equals(Roles.ADMIN),and maybe pass that around as an attribute to the jsp for showing/hiding, etc

Comment: I also added a filter for all requests that gets the google user. If the google user is not null, I call a DAO to see if the user has an account on my app (google user id = user key). I use this information to create attributes, so that all of the other servlets/jsps will know whether or not the user has been authenticated, whether or not they have an account etc. So, for example, if someone goes to /register, the servlet checks the attribute that was set in the filter to see if the user already has an account. If they do, I can redirect them to the account page, if not, take them to register.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is reasonable.  You are correct that 'administrators' in a gae app are responsible for the program itself, not for what the app.  You need your own authorization scheme to distinguish your application-level administrators from normal users.